# How to know if /dev/hda2 is Primary partition or Extended partition

Tags: filesystems, partition, devices

If all four primary partitions exist on an IDE drive, they are numbered
 as follows:

- /dev/hda1
- /dev/hda2
- /dev/hda3
- /dev/hda4

We have also the partitions on a disk with one primary partition and the sole extended partition might be numbered as
 follows:

- /dev/hda1 (primary)
- /dev/hda2 (extended)

This naming strategy leads to confusion :
How it is named : `/dev/hda2`  in both of cases :

- Primary partition
- Extended Partition

Another way to express the issue : How to distinct if it is primary or extended partition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From terminal, you type `parted /dev/hda`
then type `print`
as result:

```
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags     
 1      32.3kB  107MB  107MB  primary  ext3         boot, raid
 2      107MB   250GB  250GB  primary               raid
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of `fdisk -l /dev/hda` or a similar tool (`sfdisk -l /dev/hda`, `parted -l`, …).

You can't tell whether a partition is primary or extended from its number. In the classic PC partition scheme, each partition numbered 1, 2, 3 or 4 can be either primary or extended. (It's possible but not recommended to have multiple extended partitions; Linux itself doesn't mind but some management tools do.)

There's an almost-guaranteed way to check without root access: you can look up the size of each partition in `/proc/partitions`. The size of extended partitions is always reported as a single block. For instance, in the example below, `sda4` is an extended partition.

```
major minor  #blocks  name
…
   8        1     489951 sda1
   8        4          1 sda4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try `sudo cfdisk /dev/hda` to display a table with all partitions. It also shows whether it is a primary or extended partition.

Comment: cfdisk Does not existed on red-hat . There is sfdisk

Comment: Can't you download it from repositories?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted only the path of the primary partition, and came up with this.

```
sudo fdisk -l 2> /dev/null | awk '$2 ~ /\*/ {print $1}'
```

- `fdisk -l` lists out the partitions,
- `2> /dev/null` redirects error messages so that they don't print; I kept getting a message about a partition not being on the physical disk,
- Pipe to `awk` to process the output:

  - `$2` refers to the second word (the value of the `Boot` column),
  - `$2 ~ /^\*$/` refers to matching only lines where the second word is an asterisk only,
  - `{print $1}` prints the first word in the line matching the preceding expression, which is the `Device` column.